# Any idea why I'm getting uncaught in promise error with no reference to my code?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

this is the error

```
    ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
    at resolvePromise (root\to\workspace\dist\server.js:1040:31)
    at resolvePromise (root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:997:17)
    at root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:1099:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:647:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:7804:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:646:36)
    at Zone.runTask root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:414:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:821:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:726:21)
    at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (root\to\workspace\dist\dist\server.js:711:48)
  rejection: [Error],
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Error] },
  zone:
   Zone {
     _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
     _parent:
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '<root>',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     _name: 'angular',
     _zoneDelegate:
      ZoneDelegate {
        _taskCounts: [Object],
        zone: [Circular],
        _parentDelegate: [Object],
        _forkZS: null,
        _forkDlgt: null,
        _forkCurrZone: [Object],
        _interceptZS: null,
        _interceptDlgt: null,
        _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
        _invokeZS: [Object],
        _invokeDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
        _handleErrorZS: [Object],
        _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
        _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
        _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
        _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
        _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _hasTaskZS: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
        _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
  task:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Error] },
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
```

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but the line references where this error is throw is in Universal Code? I think it's something to do with lazy loading of modules but I'm not sure what this error means.

I also posted this as a bug to the universal github page:

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1063

but I don't know if this is actually a bug or my code.

Please ask for more information if this isn't enough, I don't know what information to give due to how unspecific this error is. (to me anyway)